# Ninject: Bind multiple types to the same singleton instance

Tags: c#, ninject

```
interface IService<T> {}

class ConcreteServiceA<T> : IService<T> {}
```

I need that:

```
IService<string> stringServices = kernel.Get<IService<string>>();
ConcreteServiceA<string> concreteStringServiceA = kernel.Get<ConcreteServiceA<string>>();

Assert.IsSameReference(stringService, concreteStringServiceA);
```

Up to now, I've tried to create bindings:

```
this.Bind(typeof(IService<>))
    .To(typeof(ConcreteServiceA<>))
    .InSingletonScope();

this.Bind(typeof(ConcreteServiceA<>)).ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

Nevertheless, using this binding I'm getting two different instances when i request for a `IService<string>` and for a `ConcreteServiceA<string>`:

```
kernel.Get<IService<string>>() instance is different of kernel.Get<ConcreteService<string>>()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify multiple types to bind at the same time, e.g.:

```
this.Bind(typeof(IService<>), typeof(ConcreteServiceA<>))
    .To(typeof(ConcreteServiceA<>))
    .InSingletonScope();
```

Some tests I made to confirm this:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IList<>)).To(typeof(List<>)).InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(List<>)).ToSelf().InSingletonScope();

var list1 = kernel.Get<IList<string>>();
var list2 = kernel.Get<List<string>>();

Assert.IsTrue(list1.Equals(list2)); // fails as per your question


kernel.Bind(typeof(IList<>), typeof(List<>)).To(typeof(List<>)).InSingletonScope();

var list1 = kernel.Get<IList<string>>();
var list2 = kernel.Get<List<string>>();

Assert.IsTrue(list1.Equals(list2)); // passes
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Just out of curiosity, what if you request for a third `var list3 = kernel.Get<List<object>>()`? I'm gessing that: `Assert.IsFalse(list1.Equals(list3))`, isn't it?