# Multiple interfaces binded to a single class

Tags: ninject

I have these 3 interfaces:

```
interface IA {}
interface IB {}
interface IC {}
```

Also, I've this other interface which inherits from `IA`, `IB` and `IC`:

```
interface II : IA, IB, IC {}
```

Then, I've also created a class `CC` inherits from `II`:

```
class CC : II {}
```

I've created these bindings:

```
this.Bind<IA>().To<CC>().InSingletonScope();
this.Bind<IB>().To<CC>().InSingletonScope();
this.Bind<IC>().To<CC>().InSingletonScope();
this.Bind<II>().To<CC>().InSingletonScope();
```

I don't know if, each time I've to request for a whichever interface, NInject kernel is going to give the same singleton instance of `CC`.

So, I mean:

```
IA ia = kernel.Get<IA>();
IB ib = kernel.Get<IB>();
```

`ia` is the same instance that `ib`?

How could I get this behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding singleton to multiple services in Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147996/binding-singleton-to-multiple-services-in-ninject)

Comment: the difference to [your question from almost exactly one year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125455/ninject-bind-multiple-types-to-the-same-singleton-instance) is minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this should work :

```
this.Bind<IA, IB, IC, II>().To<CC>().InSingletonScope();
```

The overload of `Bind` takes up to four type parameters.

Comment: And if four is not enough, there is always `Bind(params Type[] services)`.